# Can't connect to computer via VNC running x11vnc

Tags: vnc

I've got a desktop computer and a laptop, both running Ubuntu 14.04. The desktop has x11vnc installed on it and my laptop has Remmina. My desktop also has SSH running on it.

I want to use Remmina to connect via VNC to my Desktop computer. I use to have the command `x11vnc -usepw -forever` set to run on startup, but I disabled it. Now I want to set it to run on startup again. Here is the problem though: when I use SSH to run `x11vnc -usepw -forever`, I get an interesting error on the computer running x11vnc (what I want to connect to). The error is below. P.S. My laptop's IP address is 10.0.0.7.

```
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Got connection from client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:08   other clients:
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Normal socket connection
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
14/07/2014 13:21:08   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
14/07/2014 13:21:08 incr accepted_client=1 for 10.0.0.7:36678  sock=11
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Client Protocol Version 3.8
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
14/07/2014 13:21:08 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 2
14/07/2014 13:21:08 authProcessClientMessage: authentication failed from 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:08 rfbAuthProcessClientMessage: password check failed
14/07/2014 13:21:08 rfbClientSendString("password check failed!")
14/07/2014 13:21:08 client_count: 0
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Client 10.0.0.7 gone
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Statistics             events    Transmit/ RawEquiv ( saved)
14/07/2014 13:21:08  TOTALS              :      0 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
14/07/2014 13:21:08 Statistics             events    Received/ RawEquiv ( saved)
14/07/2014 13:21:08  TOTALS              :      0 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
14/07/2014 13:21:10 Got connection from client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:10   other clients:
14/07/2014 13:21:10 Normal socket connection
14/07/2014 13:21:10 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
14/07/2014 13:21:10   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
14/07/2014 13:21:10 incr accepted_client=2 for 10.0.0.7:36679  sock=11
14/07/2014 13:21:10 Client Protocol Version 3.8
14/07/2014 13:21:10 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
14/07/2014 13:21:10 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 2
14/07/2014 13:21:11 created   xdamage object: 0x1e00024
14/07/2014 13:21:16 client useCopyRect: 10.0.0.7 0
14/07/2014 13:21:16 client_set_net: 10.0.0.7  0.0243
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Pixel format for client 10.0.0.7:
14/07/2014 13:21:16   8 bpp, depth 8
14/07/2014 13:21:16   true colour: max r 7 g 7 b 3, shift r 0 g 3 b 6
14/07/2014 13:21:16 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type ultraZip
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Using compression level 9 for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Using image quality level 0 for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Using JPEG subsampling 1, Q15 for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling cursor position updates for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling KeyboardLedState protocol extension for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling SupportedMessages protocol extension for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling SupportedEncodings protocol extension for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Enabling ServerIdentity protocol extension for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Using tight encoding for client 10.0.0.7
14/07/2014 13:21:16 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: read: Connection reset by peer
14/07/2014 13:21:16 client_count: 0
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
14/07/2014 13:21:16 Client 10.0.0.7 gone
```

Comment: why not to connect via _vncviewer_: `sudo apt-get install ssvnc` ?

Comment: How well does that work with Xubuntu? Besides, I need something that is easy to configure, although I guess it is time to switch. I have had lots of problems with x11vnc. I will look into it.

Comment: As it turns out, it was a problem with my VNC client! Problem solved.

Comment: Please post your answer to your own question so we can quickly see this is solved and how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

In the faq http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq it states, that the vnc client must have the same colordepth as x11vnc

This helped for me.